# Not allowed to ask a relevant question

Tags: discussion, off-topic, questions

I asked what I thought to be a simple [question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/70411/22829) about how to ground shielded twisted pair cables, and it was closed as off-topic without any assistance on re-wording the question to be on-topic, over a question of semantics of home vs. business networks and ethernet category label. This is my business, not a home. These labels exist, but they aren't relevant to the question.

- Does this forum not cover hardware?
- Are technical questions off-topic?

I need some assistance on re-wording this question to be on-topic. The moderator told me to "don't ask us, ask an expert". I've had really good experiences on other StackExchange sites, but I'm not sure how to handle this. I know my question is probably in the Help queue somewhere, but I have to admit, I'm lost here. I wasn't trying to start an argument, but I immediately felt like I was on defense in this forum.

Answer (score 1):

Your question was about network cabling in a house. Residential/home networking is explicitly off-topic for Network Engineering, and you were correctly pointed to Super User, where home networking, including cabling in a house are on-topic. Even the picture in your question is a picture of a residential cable panel (the displayed terminations cannot handle Category-6 or above cabling because it spreads the twists out far too much). Also, you cannot mix cabling categories, as you seem to want, and expect anything to work correctly.

You also seem to be taken in with cable vendor nonsense about Category-6e, for which there really is no standard. There is a lot of crap cable and parts sold because if you label something for a category for which there are no standards, you do not need to actually meet any standards. The cabling could be junk, and there is no standard to which you can test it.

All this points to a DIY home networking project. There is really far too much wrong with what you have and what you are doing to be considered a professional network, and you really need go get a certified cable installer to help you with your project. The necessary test equipment is quite expensive (thousands of dollars for the tester than can test Category-6 and above cabling), and a certified installer will have that, use it, and provide you with a report for each cable run, repairing any out of specification cable run. It requires much more than simple electrical connectivity for modern networking speeds. See [this answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/42697/8499) for the minimum required tests (the specifications for passing a category test suite will vary by cable category).

I understand that many people are working from home in these times, and they want NE to help with that, but the place to ask about that is on Super User, where you probably would have had some answers that would satisfy you by now, rather than spending your time arguing about home networking.

Comment: The original question really cannot be answered because you cannot mix cable categories in a cable plant and expect anything to work. That is simply not a professionally managed network. We will see if you gent any votes to reopen the question,but there have been none so far.

Comment: The community does not want off-topic questions. It is up to the community to decide what is or is not on-topic for the site. It is not for people to come in and demand that their questions be answered by the community that does not want the questions. Leaving your answer open would simply let it sit there, languishing with no answer, so we try to help and point you to where it may get answered.

Comment: @vallismortis I have deleted the post containing your insults aimed at Ron. Insulting someone when you don't get your way is not helping your case in any way, it mostly makes you look like a little child. If you're not able to behave like a grown up here, please leave.

Comment: @vallismortis In addition, I think you have gotten more than enough of an answer both here and in your original question given the fact that *this question is off topic here*. I don't see any valids arguments provided that this question would be on topic.